# Check which language is being run on operating system at runtime

Tags: c++, floating-point, operating-system

I wrote a config file which a C++ function calls in.
Since some operating systems or languages set within the operating system read floating point numbers differently, Like (`4.5` & `4,5`)

How can I check at runtime to see which operating system is being run so I know if i should read floating point numbers with a comma or a decimal point.

Any ideas?

(my code the same on both windows and linux (cross platform) but when i read in the config file which contains floating point numbers on linux it does not read in the decimal points correctly?)

Whats the way forward?

Comment: How are you reading the numbers?  Generally this would be something you handle with a locale.

Comment: In all honesty, I just do a brute-force replacement of ',' by `.` when parsing machine output. Parsing human input is a bigger project, and humans rarely have to enter floating point values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is [`locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) and the `iostream` member function [`imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue). The example code on the imbue page gives pretty much the exact function you want.

```
double d;
std::locale mylocale("");
std::cin.imbue(mylocale);
std::cin << d;
```

should end up reading the variable in the right form. You may need to get the locale name from an environment variable or similar, depending on platform. On linux it'd come from the environment variable LANG. I'm not sure about windows.

Comment: You shouldn't need to get the locale name from `LANG` or any other place. Using `""` for the name already means that the runtime should retrieve the system default.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll have to recompile your programme for different platforms anyway, it's easy enough to use compile-time defines:

```
#ifdef WIN32
/* Do Windows stuff */
#endif
#ifdef LINUX
/* Do Linux stuff */
#endif
```

Then when you compile on linux for example, use `g++ -DLINUX ...`, or pass the flag using your build system.

But I suspect that in this case, if you're trying to read floating point numbers using the user's locale in a platform-agnostic way, you're probably best off looking at the `std::locale` stuff (even though it is really horrible IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use such function as **localeconv** to get **struct lconv**, wich contains much informations about locale settinng
and **setlocale** to set locale information from **clocale** header. Here is a link to to this header: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale